# Motion - takes snapshot without motion detected

Tags: debian, webcam, motion

I've been installed the standard motion 3.2.12 package on debian 7.5.
I would like to get snapshot ONLY when motion is detected, but it still saves a picture every second without any activity in front of the camera.

I'm using a TENVIS JPT3815W IP camera

### motion.conf

here is my configuration file

```
setup_mode off
target_dir /media/videos/log/webcam

netcam_url http://webcam/snapshot.cgi
netcam_tolerant_check on
netcam_userpass admin:alpha1237

# Output frames at 1 fps when no motion is detected and increase to the
# rate given by webcam_maxrate when motion is detected (default: off)
webcam_motion off
output_all off

# detection settings 1-255 default 32
noise_level 50
# Maximum framerate for webcam streams (default: 1)
webcam_maxrate 25
pre_capture 0

framerate 25
gap 30
locate on
mail technical@live.fr

text_right "FRONT CAMERA %Y/%m/%d - %T"
text_double on

ffmpeg_cap_new on
ffmpeg_cap_motion on
ffmpeg_video_codec mpeg4

output_motion off
snapshot_interval 0

# Quality of the jpeg (in percent) images produced (default: 50)
quality 90


# Restrict webcam connections to localhost only (default: on)
webcam_localhost off

# Limits the number of images per connection (default: 0 = unlimited)
# Number can be defined by multiplying actual webcam rate by desired number of seconds
# Actual webcam rate is the smallest of the numbers framerate and webcam_maxrate
webcam_limit 0
```

### Issue

when I start motion images are stored  in /media/videos/log/webcam nearly every second. I hjust want to get images when a motion is detected and the according video clip

Any idea where the configuration fails ?

Comment: Maybe your so called "motion trigger" threshold is too high still. The system will compare images to recognise what is motion. If the pixel changes are quite close (a small variation in light, for example) and you've configured the motion program to accept that as a positive motion then what you are getting is many "false positives" - hence the many images. Try playing with the sensitivity values to reduce the number of false positives.

Comment: Check the following attributes (I'll show my values): `threshold 1500`, `framerate 4`, `minimum_motion_frames 1`, `emulate_motion off`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following attributes (I'll show my values): `snapshot_interval 0`, `threshold 1500`, `framerate 4`, `minimum_motion_frames 1`, `emulate_motion off`.

Comment: The threshold option did the trick. Thank you for your quick response.